# do centos bug fixes get included in RedHat / Fedora?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fedora

I was wondering do CentOS bug fixes get pushed upstream to RedHat or Fedora?
I imagine it's up to the maintainers of RHEL/Fedora, but I wanted to know the direction bug fixes get applied between distributions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the other way around, the bug fixes for CentOS come from upstream at Red Hat.

Typically you get CESAs like this

> CentOS Errata and Security Advisory 2012:1288 Moderate
>
> Upstream details at : https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2012-1288.html

or

> CentOS Errata and Security Advisory 2012:1284 Moderate
>
> Upstream details at : https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2012-1284.html

Comment: Can you please explain why the ability to reference CentOS bugs was added to the Red Hat Bugzilla? http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-redhat/2008-August/000025.html

Answer (score 2):

Not really Fedora bugs are pushed into RHEL, RHEL is kind of derivative from Fedora suitable for enterprises. Bug fixes, documentation and a good stuff of CentOS comes from Red Hat.

CentOS is essentially another version of RHEL which does not include paid support and no timeline of bug fix.